# How do I stop bootstraps (reactstrap) drop down menu repositioning when screen sizes change?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

In portrait mode there is enough space for the drop down menu to appear under the button that you click to show the menu:

[image: Drop down menu in correct position]

But if the screen size gets small (landscape on some mobile devices) enough, then the menu poition moves up and covers the icon:

[image: Drop down menu covering button]

This means it can be hard to close the menu without leaving landscape mode.

I'm using the same example that ReactStrap has is their documentation [here](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Dropdown, DropdownToggle, DropdownMenu, DropdownItem } from 'reactstrap';

const Example = (props) => {
  const [dropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setDropdownOpen(prevState => !prevState);

  return (
    <Dropdown isOpen={dropdownOpen} toggle={toggle}>
      <DropdownToggle caret>
        Dropdown
        </DropdownToggle>
      <DropdownMenu>
        <DropdownItem header>Header</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem>Some Action</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem disabled>Action (disabled)</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem divider />
        <DropdownItem>Foo Action</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem>Bar Action</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem>Quo Action</DropdownItem>
      </DropdownMenu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
}

export default Example;
```

I want to find a way of stoping the drop down menu moving position on screens that don't have the height for the full menu.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer I was looking for by reading through the code.

Adding `nav` and `inNavBar` to `<Dropdown>` and adding `nav` to `<DropdownToggle>` seems to have done it.

Here's the PR that introduced the value: https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/pull/692/files